# When i give routes using Navigator.push() the other screen becomes black in flutter

Tags: flutter

When i click on the menu card it leads to the black screen

[image]

I got the messed up black screen with no app bar on it instead of real screen

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:bakery_booth/Dashboard.dart';
import 'package:bakery_booth/Invoices.dart';
import 'package:bakery_booth/Menu.dart';
import 'package:bakery_booth/Orders.dart';
import 'package:bakery_booth/Profile.dart';
import 'package:bakery_booth/Timings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
    runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Center(child: Text('Welcome to Bakery Booth ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0))),
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
              shadowColor: Colors.grey[500],
              shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                 borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue,),),
              bottom: PreferredSize(preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(10),
                       child:SizedBox(height:5)),),
          body: MainScreen(),
  )));

}
class  MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(width: 20.0),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget> [
                 FlatButton(
                   onPressed: (){
                     Navigator.push(context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>DashboardScreen()));
                   },
                   child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Card(
                          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(child: Image(image: AssetImage('Image/Dashboard.png')),
                            flex: 3),
                            Expanded(child: Text('Dashboard', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)))
                          ],),
                      elevation: 10,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                      shape:  OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white

                    ),
                ))),
                 ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ProfileScreen()));
                },
                child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(child: Image(image: AssetImage('Image/Profile.png')),
                          flex: 3),
                          Expanded(child: Text('Profile', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),)

                        ],),
                        elevation: 10,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                        shape:  OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white

                          ),
                        ))),
              ),

              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MenuScreen()));
                },
                child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(child: Image(image: AssetImage('Image/Menu.png')),
                                flex: 3),
                            Expanded(child: Text('Menu', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),)

                          ],),
                        elevation: 10,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                        shape:  OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white

                          ),
                        ))),
              ),

            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 6.0),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget> [
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>OrdersScreen()));
                },
                child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Card(
                        child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(child: Image(image: AssetImage('Image/Order.png')),
                        flex: 3),
                          Expanded(child: Text('Orders', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)))
                          ],),
                        elevation: 10,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                        shape:  OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white

                          ),
                        ))),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>InvoicesScreen()));
                },
                child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Card(
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(child: Image(image: AssetImage('Image/Invoice.png')),
                              flex: 3),
                          Expanded(child: Text('Invoices', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)))
                        ],),
                        elevation: 10,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                        shape:  OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white

                          ),
                        ))),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>TimingsScreen()));
                },
                child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Card(
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(child: Image(image: AssetImage('Image/Clock.png')),
                              flex: 3),
                          Expanded(child: Text('Timings', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)))
                        ],),
                        elevation: 10,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                        shape:  OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white

                          ),
                        ))),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code for my main screen. All the other cards like dashboard, Profile, Order, invoices, Timings are working fine they are leading to new screen properly but the menu card does not lead to menu screen the same way other card does. it turns black i don't know why.

Comment: Can you please provide the code of `MenuScreen`?

Comment: Not using scaffold in your menu screen?

Comment: Seems like others screens are missing scaffold.

Comment: Maybe removing the scaffold inside the material app and inserting it to the main screen will fix this.